# Image Gallery tie in with database?

Tags: php, mysql, image-processing

I'm developing an image gallery for one of my customers, they want a very minimal, simple and easy user experience. The image gallery must contain a title and description of each image, we have created a app to upload the images and set titles and descriptions this is stored in a mySQL database. We're developing this site with php.

Before I go off and develop this, does anyone know of any opensource galleries that tie into a mySQL database with similar functionality? Or maybe this approach is naive? Maybe I should approach this from a different direction and not use a mySQL backend..

Any advice is very welcome.
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one looks decent: http://gallery.menalto.com/. It supports MySQL and a bunch of other DBs.

For something this simple, you could get by without a database (however I doubt you would be able to have a title and description for the images without using a flat-file database; not recommended). To do it without a database, try this: http://spgm.sourceforge.net/.

However, if you already have written the uploader which works with MySQL, I would go with the database option and tweak it if necessary to work with the first link I posted.